# UNC-paths for read.csv in R

Tags: r, unc

So I have a problem with UNC paths. According to other unc related topic, the correct form should be:

```
source <- read.csv("\\\\W:\\Reports\\report.csv")
```

but then I got the error message:

```
Error in file(file, "rt") : cannot open the connection
In addition: Warning message:
In file(file, "rt") :
  cannot open file '\\W:\Reports\report.csv': Invalid argument
```

As a user I have access to that very folder and file - I am positive about it.

Comment: If you replace the backslashes with forward slashes, you can use Windows paths in R easily. So, `W:/Reports/report.csv` for instance.

Comment: Try using `file.choose()` to find the path.

Answer (score 1):

You are not using UNC paths.  A UNC path would be something like `"\\\\myserver\\C$\\Users"` or `"//myserver/C$/Users"`or `"//myserver/Users"`.  What you are using is a mapped drive or a mapped network drive.  They are an alternative to UNC paths.  Try this instead:

```
read.csv("W:\\Reports\\report.csv")
```

or forward slashes:

```
read.csv("W:/Reports/report.csv")
```

Comment: Unfortunately, both don't work. W: is indeed a mapped drive, the unc path in this case is \\spplfapcen05\. So my code is 
source <- read.csv("\\\\spplfapcen05\\Reports\\report.csv")

Comment: You likely have the path wrong then.  Type `file.choose()` at the R prompt and navigate to the `report.csv` file.  Then, when you press Open in the navigation dialogue, R will return the path.